# Restart issue for bluetooth in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, bluetooth

I don't want to run `sudo systemctl start bluetooth` command after every restart to turn on my bluetooth service in kali linux; how to keep it running?

I tried googling but couldn't find; also can you explain me why bluetooth service is turning off after shutdown in linux but why not in windows?

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth`

Comment: I would suggest [holding off on using Kali](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) until you have a good grasp of basic Linux use & administration. Enabling services and checking the man page for `systemctl` would fall under the basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If the Bluetooth service does not start automatically after boot, it means that it is disabled.

You can check this with the command

```
systemctl is-enabled bluetooth
```

To enable it, run

```
systemctl enable bluetooth
```

This effectively starts the service at boot, so you won't need to run it each time via

```
systemctl start bluetooth
```

(All previous commands must be run as root, or by prepending `sudo` if run by a unprivileged user.)

You can read more about systemd in a lot of Linux docs, for instance [here](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd) (Kali is Debian-based).